# How do I write an "IF" statement for MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

I am using MS Access 2003 SP3 and I need to write a statement that says something like this:

I have two columns, one is the [MaxOfDate] field and the other is the [Date-Inidicator] field. For several of these rows, the Date-Indicator is blank. I want to tell MS Access that if the [MaxOfDate] field is a date of ""99991231" then enter "A" in [Date-Indicator]. How do I write this in an IF STATEMENT?

Thank you,
Debbie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false )

iif ([Qty] > 5, "greater than 5", "less than 5")